# text-ellipsis to text in first span

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I want to make like this:

- Two `span`(`span.title`, `span.date`) in one line.
- `span.date` is next of `span.title` (not align right side of parent)
- `span.title` should be text-overflow: ellipsis (not `span.date`)

```js
var title = document.querySelector('.title');
var text = title.innerText;
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  if (title.innerText.length > 30) {
    title.innerText = text;
  }
  else {
    title.innerText = text.repeat(30);
  }
}

/* Polyfill */
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');
    }
    var str = '' + this;
    count = +count;
    if (count != count) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
    }
    if (count == Infinity) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
    }
    count = Math.floor(count);
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
      return '';
    }
    // Ensuring count is a 31-bit integer allows us to heavily optimize the
    // main part. But anyway, most current (August 2014) browsers can't handle
    // strings 1 << 28 chars or longer, so:
    if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');
    }
    var rpt = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      rpt += str;
    }
    return rpt;
  }
}
```

```css
div.line {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 110px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.date {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="title">Long Title</span>
  <span class="date">2017-08-27</span>
</div>
<div>
<button>toggle title</button>
</div>
```

In this way, Second span must has fixed width.
But in my case, both span cannot have fixed width.

How can I made this?

- I already know the way to use Javascript. But I want to know the way without Javascript.

Comment: its already working I suppose? what's not working if I may?

Comment: @kukkuz yes, its work. But, its not work if the remove width of `span.date` Because `span.date`'s text can be change to longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can do this:

1. Replace `inline-block` with `flex` for `line`.
2. Remove `padding-right`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` and and `overflow:hidden` from `line`.
3. Add the *ellipsis* to `title`:

   ```
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   ```
4. Remove *absolute* positioning of the `date`.

See demo below:

```js
var title = document.querySelector('.title');
var text = title.innerText;
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  if (title.innerText.length > 30) {
    title.innerText = text;
  }
  else {
    title.innerText = text.repeat(30);
  }
}

/* Polyfill */
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');
    }
    var str = '' + this;
    count = +count;
    if (count != count) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
    }
    if (count == Infinity) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
    }
    count = Math.floor(count);
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
      return '';
    }
    // Ensuring count is a 31-bit integer allows us to heavily optimize the
    // main part. But anyway, most current (August 2014) browsers can't handle
    // strings 1 << 28 chars or longer, so:
    if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');
    }
    var rpt = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      rpt += str;
    }
    return rpt;
  }
}
```

```css
div.line {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* ADDED THIS */
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*padding-right: 110px;*/
  max-width: 100%;
  /*overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  /* ADDED THESE */
  padding-right: 10px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.date {
  /*position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;*/
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <span class="title">Long Title</span>
  <span class="date">2017-08-27</span>
</div>
<div>
<button>toggle title</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @TaeSangCho let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: It's a good idea. But flex box is support after ie11. I cannot use this TT